# how to write excel vba coding for left function inside vlookup, or covert from excel function to vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use below function from excel on vba. Can I have a good solution?

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(B4,3),B2:G349,5,FALSE),"")

I will appreciate if I get a solution!

```
Dim lookFor As Range
Dim table_array As Range
Dim varResult As Variant
Dim table_array_col As Integer
Dim lookFor_col As Integer

On Error Resume Next

Set lookFor = Range([B4], Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(3)) 
Set table_array = Range("B2:G349")
table_array_col = 5
varResult = Application.VLookup(left(lookFor.Value,3), table_array, table_array_col, 0)
lookFor_col = 2
lookFor.offest(0, lookFor_col) = varResult
```

Comment: what I want to use left function is range variable.

Comment: `offest` should be `offset`.

Comment: vlookup doesn't take more than a single value in its *lookup_value* argument. For that matter, neither does Left.

Comment: I'm unclear what .End you are attempting with *3*. xlUp is -4162.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of looking up `LEFT(Range([B4], Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(3))) ` within `B2:B439` on the same worksheet?

Comment: I'd like to use vlookup using left function because the ref value is too long to check. the 3 letter is enough to check for vlookup ref value.

Comment: and I am sorry that  is not real code.  in fact, Set table_array = Range("B2:G349") is Set table_array = Worksheets("refSheet1").Range("B2:G349")

Comment: Do I have to use For each function to change whole value of ref table range before using vlookup?

Comment: I guess the error is literally caused by the first 3 letters of your `vlookup` value are not match with all the values in the `table_array`. For example, `DAC` is not match with `DAC1231123`.

Answer (score 0):

Use variant Array.

```
Sub test()
    Dim lookFor As Variant
    Dim Table As Variant
    Dim vResult() As Variant
    Dim table_array_col As Integer
    Dim lookFor_col As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim LookC As Integer
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim r As Long, r2 As Long

    c = 5 '<~~ col
    LookC = 4


    lookFor = Range([B4], Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(3))
    Table = Range("B2:G349")


    r = UBound(lookFor, k)
    r2 = UBound(Table, 1)

    ReDim vResult(1 To r, 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To r
        For j = 1 To r2
            If Left(lookFor(i, 1), 3) = Table(j, 1) Then
                vResult(i, 1) = Table(j, c)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Cells(2, LookC).Resize(r, 1) = vResult
End Sub
```